# controlling two dc motors and servo with arduino code

Tags: arduino, controls, motordriver

The code does not seem to be working but I have also just started learning how to code arduino. I'm trying to run two dc motors and one servo as steering for a robot car. How should I wright it so it works.  All I'm trying to do is use two motors to drive the car forward and the servo to provide direction for the car.  How can I improve this code?

```
    #include <Servo.h>


    int servoRightPin = 2;
    int servoLeftPin = 3;
    int servoDirPin = 4;
    Servo servoRight;
    Servo servoLeft;
    Servo servoDir;


    void turnLeft()
    {
    servoDir.write(0.6);
    delay(300000);
    servoLeft.write(180);
    servoRight.write(0);
    }

    void moveForward()
    {
    servoDir.write(0);
    delay(240000);
    servoLeft.write(180);
    servoRight(0);
    }

    void turnLeft()
    {
    servoDir.write(0.6);
    delay(300000);
    servoLeft.write(180);
    servoRight.write(0);
    }

    void moveForward()
    {
    servoDir.write(0);
    delay(240000);
    servoLeft.write(180);
    servoRight(0);
    }




    june_4_car.ino: In function 'void moveForward()':
    june_4_car.ino:25:15: error: no match for call to '(Servo) (int)'
    june_4_car.ino: In function 'void turnLeft()':
    june_4_car.ino:28:6: error: redefinition of 'void turnLeft()'
    june_4_car.ino:12:6: error: 'void turnLeft()' previously defined here
    june_4_car.ino: In function 'void moveForward()':
    june_4_car.ino:36:6: error: redefinition of 'void moveForward()'
    june_4_car.ino:20:6: error: 'void moveForward()' previously defined here
    june_4_car.ino:41:15: error: no match for call to '(Servo) (int)'
    Error compiling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems there.

Let's start with the compilation errors:

1. You have two functions `turnLeft` and two functions `moveForward`. I assume the second pair should be `turnRight` and `moveBackwards`.
2. In the `moveForward` function you call `servoRight(0)` this should probably be `servoRight.write(0)`.

Fixing this should allow your code to compile, but it will still not work:

1. You have defined pins but they are not attached to servos (no call to `attach`).
2. You mentioned one servo and two dc motors so why does your code have three servos? (only one of the servo three pins is connected to a digital port the other two are for power).
3. What's with the `delay`, `write(180)` and `write(0)` what are you trying to do there?
4. write(0.6) is not going to increase the angle by 0.6 degrees. You need to either keep track of the current angle or `read()` it from the `servo`.

In short read some tutorials ([like this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-14-servo-motors/)), experiment and have fun.

Comment: Technically I want the robot to go around an outdoor running track.  I calculated that the steering servo has to turn 0.6 degrees left to make the turn, according to the length of the robot and the radius of the curved part of the track.  Since there are two straights and two curves on a track, I had the robot repeat turning left and going straight twice.  Also how can I make the servos run for a certain amount of time?  For example, what if I want the the servos to run for 240 seconds on the straights and 300 seconds on the curves? I used the delay for that, but noticed it's wrong function.

Comment: the only function I found to run dc motors was the motors.write function, but you can only use that for the Arduino robot kit.  I used servoLeft and servoRight to run dc motors instead? is this possible?